# Cyborg detective story, hunting biohackers

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

From a group on Facebook, thought I'd try and help out as it sounds like a good read.

> I need help finding a novel I once read
> when I was a kid. It was about this detective that was a cyborg. The
> novel had a heavy ghost in the shell vibe. I don't remember much but
> there was a case with headless kids in garbage containers and about a
> pilot who's visor turned out to be hacked and plane crashed. The main
> character was a biohacker turned detective and now captures other bio
> hackers.  I remember he had a chip that allowed him to browse web with
> his thoughts and display built in his retinas and all sorts of
> auxillary cybernetic and chemical systems that would kick in action if
> some of his vital organs were damaged. I tried searching for the book
> on google many times but without any luck.
>
> EDIT: I think the last case was something about  hacked military micro
> drones. They were like for riot control but somene reprogammed them to
> shoot at everyone.  And I remember the chip or a card that was vital
> to shut them down,  something along this lines.

**Edited to add**

- Probably from the 1990s
- Not *Altered Carbon*

Comment: Welcome =) It's a shame the OP hasn't included when they were a kid, is it at all possible for you to find that out? The more items on [this list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) you can tick off the better, but having said that, I've seen mysteries solved with a lot less than this and it seems like there's a fair bit of detail here which is good

Comment: He said he read it in around 2000. I'll see if I can glean any more details from that list too

Comment: Do the suggestions here help? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113421/sci-fi-detective-novel-genetically-modified-humans